# Can't go inside BIOS

Tags: windows, bios

I can't open BIOS in my laptop Sony Vaio. I already removed the HDD and DVDrom, and see message that BootNG is missing.

I booted in bios before. There was a password and one day I forgot it, but remember and change settings from UEFI to Legacy and after that I can't go inside.

Comment: are you sure you typed it correctly? can you confirm the exact message and what are you trying to do to get to BIOS? Also, have you ever booted into BIOS on this machine before

Comment: http://community.sony.com/t5/VAIO-Upgrade-Backup-Recovery/How-can-I-enter-bios-on-my-vaio-I-want-to-boot-from-the-cd-drive/td-p/60063 may eventually help you too. But you should tell us which model you have.

Comment: Exact message without HDD and DVD is "Operating System Not Found".

Comment: I have Sony vaio SVE 1512s1rw. It does not help, I am trying to fix it already 24 hours and can't.

Comment: Yes, I booted in bios before. There was a password and one day I forgot it, but remember and change settings from UEFI to Legacy and after that I can't go inside.

Comment: Well, there is no surprise that you get a message "Operating System Not Found" after you removed the disk where your operation system is. What else did you expect?

Comment: I expect to be able to enter BIOS, I believe it not in HDD.

Comment: Well, then why did you remove the HDD in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Turn off your PC
- Press <kbd>Assist</kbd>
- Keep pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>

Comment: Oh my God, thank you so much. It really helps.

Comment: Glad it helped.